# (androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, dialog

I get error : "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference" while trying to draw recyclerview on a dialog box

Below is my code for the same.

```
public void openreview(View view) {
    rv_review=view.findViewById(R.id.rv_test);
    adapter_review = new mcqAdapter(this, nowStory);
    rv_review.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rv_review.setAdapter(adapter_review);
    adapter_review.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    slctssn.show();
}
```

More details of error says that the setting layout is making the error.
Could you pls anybody help me..

Comment: The error states that your recycler view is null. Make sure you have entered correct view ID in findviewbyId.

Comment: element id is correct, also the recycler is created as public.

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: Moreover kindly attach the XML file too.

Comment: I fixed by  modifying the recyclerview creation like this : rv_review=(RecyclerView)slctssn.findViewById(R.id.rv_test); findviewbyid was to be referring to the dialog view